# I have indices in one tensor and values in another. How do I create a new tensor with this?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say my indices are:

```
indices = [6, 9, 2],
          [2, 2, 7],
          [0, 8, 4]
```

and my values are:

```
values = [0.35764236, 0.47342054, 0.61403205, 0.01948093, 0.21791322,
       0.53855718, 0.93596267, 0.3948243 , 0.22061542, 0.09633507]
```

Then in numpy I can simply do

```
new_array = values[indices]
```

to get:

```
new_array = [0.93596267, 0.09633507, 0.61403205]
            [0.61403205, 0.61403205, 0.3948243 ]
            [0.35764236, 0.22061542, 0.21791322]
```

This seems to not work in tensorflow 2. Neither am I able to use loops to assign values nor am I able to convert to numpy as I'm in a model.call. Is there a simple way of doing this in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple ways.

```
indices = [[6, 9, 2],
          [2, 2, 7],
          [0, 8, 4]]

values = [0.35764236, 0.47342054, 0.61403205, 0.01948093, 0.21791322,
       0.53855718, 0.93596267, 0.3948243 , 0.22061542, 0.09633507]

print(tf.gather(values,indices))
```

Output :

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.9359627  0.09633507 0.61403203]
 [0.61403203 0.61403203 0.3948243 ]
 [0.35764235 0.22061542 0.21791323]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

You can also assign and slice.